# Elasticsearch DSL query from an SQL statement

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch.  I don't think I fully understand the concept of query and filters.  In my case I just want to use filters as I don't want to use advance feature like scoring.

How would I convert the following SQL statement into elasticsearch query?

```
SELECT * FROM advertiser 
WHERE company like '%com%' 
AND sales_rep IN (1,2)
```

What I have so far:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/advertisers/advertiser/_search?pretty=true' -d ' 
 { 
     "query" : { 
         "bool" : { 
             "must" : { 
                 "wildcard" : { "company" : "*com*" } 
             } 
         } 
     }, 
     "size":1000000 

}'
```

How to I add the OR filters on sales_rep field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "should" clause after your must clause.  In a bool query, one or more should clauses must match by default.  Actually, you can set the "minimum_number_should_match" to be any number, Check out the [bool query docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html).

For your case, this should work.

```
    "should" : [
        {
            "term" : { "sales_rep_id" : "1" }
        },
        {
            "term" : { "sales_rep_id" : "2" }
        }
    ],
```

The same concept works for bool filters.  Just change "query" to "filter".  The bool filter docs are [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

I come across this post 4 years too late...

Anyways, perhaps the following code could be useful...

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "company": "*com*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "sales_rep_id": [ "1", "2" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```